# how to execute events asynchronously in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous

Pls I'm still new to laravel and I have used events in laravel a couple of times but I'm curious and would like to know if it's possible to execute an event in laravel asynchronously. Like for instance in the code below:

```
    <?php

    namespace mazee\Http\Controllers;

   class maincontroller extends Controller
   {
    public  function index(){
       Event::fire(new newaccountcreated($user)) ;
      //do something

    }
```

Is it possible for the block of code in the event listener of the "newaccountcreated" event to be executed asynchronously after the event is fired ?

Comment: No. Because php process has one thread always. Yes, its possible, but not for Laravel, I presume.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes of course this is possible. You should read about [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues). Every driver (only not *sync* driver) are async. The easiest to configure is the `database` driver, but you can also want to try [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) server , here is [Laravel bundle](https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq) for it.

You can also add to your EventListener: `newaccountcreated` trait `Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue` (you can read about him [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events#manually-accessing-the-queue)) which will helps you to connect it with Laravel Queue.

Answer (score 1):

Filip's answer covers it all. I will add a bit more to it. If you push an event it will goto the default queue. You can specify a queue name as well. Have the listener class implements ShouldQueue and just include the queue method in the listener class like below.

```
/**
 * Push a new job onto the queue.
**/
public function queue($queue, $job, $data)
{
    return $queue->pushOn('queue-name', $job, $data);
}
```